# How to split a string without using arrays or split function in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, substring

I have a string in which each value is separated using "|" as following:

```
698301    | 48380.80                   | sam                            | aass@gmail.com                 | 5675767        | 3     | 40602.80           | 7778
```

I want to split this string at once without using array or split function in c# and want to store each splitted value in different variables  so that i can use these variables for my code later for example:

> a= 69801, b= 48380.80, c= sam, d= aass@gmail.com, e= 5675767, f= 3, g=40602.80, h=7778

i have tried `"indexOf"` function but it is not working as expected.

code which i have used:

```
        var hyphenIndex = str.IndexOf("|");
        var a = str.Substring(0, hyphenIndex);
        MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());

        var b = str.Substring(1, hyphenIndex);
        MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());

        var c = str.Substring(2, hyphenIndex);
        MessageBox.Show(c.ToString());

        var d = str.Substring(3, hyphenIndex);
        MessageBox.Show(d.ToString());

        var e = str.Substring(4, hyphenIndex);
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

        var f = str.Substring(5, hyphenIndex);
        MessageBox.Show(f.ToString());

        var g = str.Substring(6, hyphenIndex);
        MessageBox.Show(g.ToString());

        var h = str.Substring(7, hyphenIndex);
        MessageBox.Show(h.ToString());
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you tried and describe how it didn't work? Also, it would be helpful to copy and paste your input/output rather than using screenshots. That way others don't need to type it all out if they want to help you.

Comment: It seems like `string.Split` would be the ideal way to split a string.  How is it not the right tool for the job?

Comment: @Nysaa i cannot use it as use of array is restricted in my code

Comment: Is this homework for a class? Thats a truly bizarre restraint otherwise. You'll want to parse the string yourself then. `IndexOf` will only work the first time until you create a new string that is a substring from that index to the end of the string. You'll repeat this process : Create a substring from the beginning of the string to the first instance of `|` which you find with indexOf. Assign the result to your chosen variable. Create a new substring from that index to the end of the string. Repea until you're out of strings.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Gabriel  yes it is

Comment: @DetectivePikachu thank you will try that

Comment: You're really really close. You're only missing two steps. Create a substring from the original string each step that cuts off the first section you took. Then, update hyphenIndex by calling IndexOf again.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu can you please give an example !! it will be really helpful as i am new in c#

Comment: Sure, let me post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a function that can get the value of a column by index, then reuse that as needed. Here is an example:

```cs
public string GetValue(string row, int index)
{
    var start = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < index; i++)
        start = row.IndexOf('|', start + 1);
    var end = row.IndexOf('|', start + 1);
    if (end == -1)
        end = row.Length;
    return row.Substring(start, end - start)
              .Replace("|", string.Empty).Trim();
}

var str = "698301 | 48380.80 | sam | aass@gmail.com | 5675767 | 3 | 40602.80 | 7778";
var a = GetValue(str, 0);
var b = GetValue(str, 1);
var c = GetValue(str, 2);
var d = GetValue(str, 3);
var e = GetValue(str, 4);
var f = GetValue(str, 5);
var g = GetValue(str, 6);
var h = GetValue(str, 7);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, you just have to make sure you're cutting off the part of the string that you used, and updating your index with the new location of the first `|` in the string. Changing the name to `delimiterIndex` just because calling a pipe a hyphen bugs me :P

Make special note that we have to go one past the index provided by `IndexOf` when doing our substring to make sure we have cut out the `|` from the result string. When we provide the length for the substring, we must take this extra 1 character into account as it will reduce the overall length of the resultant string.

```
    string s = "698301 | 48380.80 | sam | aass@gmail.com | 5675767 | 3 | 40602.80 | 7778";

    string a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;

    int delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|');
    a = s.Substring(0, delimiterIndex);
    s = s.Substring(delimiterIndex + 1 , s.Length - delimiterIndex - 1);

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|');
    b = s.Substring(0, delimiterIndex);
    s = s.Substring(delimiterIndex + 1 , s.Length - delimiterIndex - 1);

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|');
    c = s.Substring(0, delimiterIndex);
    s = s.Substring(delimiterIndex + 1 , s.Length - delimiterIndex - 1);

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|');
    d = s.Substring(0, delimiterIndex);
    s = s.Substring(delimiterIndex + 1 , s.Length - delimiterIndex - 1);

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|');
    e = s.Substring(0, delimiterIndex);
    s = s.Substring(delimiterIndex + 1 , s.Length - delimiterIndex - 1);

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|');
    f = s.Substring(0, delimiterIndex);
    s = s.Substring(delimiterIndex + 1 , s.Length - delimiterIndex - 1);

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|');
    g = s.Substring(0, delimiterIndex);
    s = s.Substring(delimiterIndex + 1 , s.Length - delimiterIndex - 1);

    h = s;
```

As Chris Dunaway suggested, this can be further refined to remove the substrings of the source string using the overload for IndexOf which takes a start index. This would look like the following

```
    string s = "698301 | 48380.80 | sam | aass@gmail.com | 5675767 | 3 | 40602.80 | 7778";

    string a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;

    int lastIndex = 0;
    int delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|', 0);
    a = s.Substring(lastIndex, delimiterIndex);
    lastIndex = delimiterIndex;

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|', delimiterIndex+1);
    b = s.Substring(lastIndex + 1, delimiterIndex - lastIndex - 1);
    lastIndex = delimiterIndex;

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|', delimiterIndex+1);
    c = s.Substring(lastIndex + 1, delimiterIndex - lastIndex - 1);
    lastIndex = delimiterIndex;

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|', delimiterIndex+1);
    d = s.Substring(lastIndex + 1, delimiterIndex - lastIndex - 1);
    lastIndex = delimiterIndex;

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|', delimiterIndex+1);
    e = s.Substring(lastIndex + 1, delimiterIndex - lastIndex - 1);
    lastIndex = delimiterIndex;

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|', delimiterIndex+1);
    f = s.Substring(lastIndex + 1, delimiterIndex - lastIndex - 1);
    lastIndex = delimiterIndex;

    delimiterIndex = s.IndexOf('|', delimiterIndex+1);
    g = s.Substring(lastIndex + 1, delimiterIndex - lastIndex - 1);
    lastIndex = delimiterIndex;

    h = s.Substring(lastIndex + 1);
```

Comment: There is no reason to create so many temporary strings using `Substring`.  The `IndexOf` method has an overload where you can pass in the starting location to begin searching.  For each successive search update `delimiterIndex` by 1.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Can you please give an example!! it will be really helpful as i am pretty new in c#

Comment: Yes that is certainly something you can do. I find it to be a bit harder to understand from a beginners perspective, but I've updated my answer to include this refinement below the original answer.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu if i want only 3rd or 5th value in the string which is sam and 5675767  do i have to repeat the whole process? is there any way to pick up only specified position values? like i want only c and e variables not all a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

Comment: You do have to know where the `|` characters are to pull something like that off. Since the fields aren't a fixed length it makes it a bit trickier. With `string.Split` this would be easy, because you could just take the 3rd or 5th item in the resulting array. With this approach you would have to go through it until you have what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help it is really helpful @DetectivePikachu

Comment: Happy to help! Have fun

Comment: @saurabh255 - If you need to get the 3rd or 5th value, see the answer by _Jaguir_ above.